# Align two input textbox and one button horizontally

Tags: asp.net, css

I have two inputs, one button and one drop down menu, how do i align it so that its next to each other. I have created div for each element but things dont look right. this is what i have done:

```
<div class="class1">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input1" >
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="deatPicker1">
    </div>
    <div class="class1" >
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input1">
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="deatPicker2">
    </div>

<div class="button" style="display: inline-block;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">    </i></button>
</div>
```

**My Css:** during this process i have noticed the above example works fine but only if i create another web-page if i use my current web page then things dont stay the way i want

```
 .class1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
  }
 .input1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: remove all divs and make one single div => http://jsfiddle.net/LrE78/

Comment: This is a direct copy-paste of your code, and appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mT6VV/

Comment: @NoobEditor you said remove all divs and make it single one, in you example where is .input1 class is coming from?

Comment: @xec my method works for me too but the calendar glyphicon shows a bit higher than input. do you know why?

Comment: @Dip : forgot to delete it dude, it was understood.... => http://jsfiddle.net/LrE78/2/ :p

Comment: Please create a demo showing the exact problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using bootstrap.
So you can align it all using rows and cols.

like so :

```
  <div class="row class1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>    </span>
            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="deatPicker1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>    </span>
            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="deatPicker2">
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>Search</button>
            </div>            
</div>
```

a row gives you a maximum of 12 cols.. so depending on how many aligned items you want, you can do :
`<div class="col-md-3"></div>` x 4 to get a 4 col layout

http://jsfiddle.net/mT6VV/7/

Comment: This is very interesting, it will help me learn few other things, so i have changed col-md-4 to col-md-1 so i want things one after another but in a jsfiddle when i click run nothing happens why is that?

Comment: try click update and see.. or give me link  :)
a col-md-12 gives you 12 small "boxes" in a row by the way

Comment: I've added col-md-12 and clicked updated but nothing changed: http://jsfiddle.net/mT6VV/16/#&togetherjs=odELf4mhRH - so what i want is the calendar logo on left followed by input text, padding of 3px; followed by calendar logo again and the second input. How would i lay that out in term of cols.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code :-**

```
<div class="class1">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>    </span>
</div>
<div class="input1" >
    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="deatPicker1">
</div>
<div class="class1" >
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>    </span>
</div>
<div class="input1">
    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="deatPicker2">
</div>
```

**use this Css :**

```
.class1 {
       display: inline-block;
   }
   .input1 {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 200px;
       padding-left: 20px;
   }
   button {
       width:90px;
       height:20px;
   }
```

you don't have need to put extra`div` tag in your design source.

[Demo For Alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/mT6VV/2/)
it is working.

Comment: jsfiddle shows the thing that i want, but when i use this method i get long calendar-glyphicon and input from left of my web-page to right .